# iOS: mask view in supeview coordinates for animation

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, core-graphics, quartz-graphics

Maybe I just can't see an obvious answer, but I'm struggling with creating a mask like this (Cocoa Touch):

[image: mask]

The mask and the masked view have the same superview. The mask should not have visible pixels.

The mask's position should be static theirs superview's coordinates, and said masked view should be visible only when in appears outside the mask.
The masked view position may be animated.

Thanks.

Comment: If you're dealing with regular rectangles that are the full width of your view, why not just make your superview `clipsToBounds` and move the subview to a negative y origin?

Comment: This might have something to do with the frames of the masked view and the masking view. They need to be same to get the right effect, because the masking is done relative to the frame of the view being masked. Can you share some code that shows how the mask, the masked view etc... are set up?

Comment: Thanks @IanMacDonald, I solved it with just adding superview and autolayouting stuff, no freaking masks :)